# Using a while loop in R to print three words in three iterations

Tags: r, while-loop

How do I use a while loop in R to print the phrase "My name is" using three iterations to print each word? The output should look like:

```
[1] "My"
[2] "name"
[3] "is"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a terrible exacuse for a `while` loop---generally `while` loops should be used when you don't know in advance how many iterations are needed. Here, we know we need 3 iterations, so a `for` loop (or no loop at all...) would be better.

Here's a pointless `while` loop:

```
words = c("My", "name", "is")
i = 1
while(i <= length(words)) {
  print(words[i])
  i = i + 1
}
```

Here's a more appropriate `for` loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(words)) {
  print(words[i)
}
```